# Creating readable XML for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, excel, ipad

My client uses a process that uses [XMLSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx) to create XML documents that can be opened in Microsoft Excel.  In fact, simply renaming the files to .XLS, will ensure that the documents open in Excel by default.  These documents are emailed to our clients.  The documents open successfully in for Excel for PC and MAC, as well as OpenOffice (both platforms).  It's a pretty nice solution.

The problem is, some of our clients have started attempting to open these documents (for viewing) on their iPhones and iPads (iOS devices), and it doesn't work.  We know that iOS devices can open actual Office files, but since our documents are really just XML (and not true Excel files), the viewer on iOS doesn't want to view them.  At least that's my guess.

We have played with sending these files with both XML and XLS extensions.

I'm aware of the option of using different techniques for building these documents such that they become true XLS files... but obviously, we're not eager to rewrite the entire application when most of our functionality remains just fine.

Any tips, ideas, suggestions?

Comment: I think this would fit Superuser more than Stack Overflow. SO is a programming Q&A site, and since there isn't any code...

Comment: Have you tried giving the file an .xlsx file extension?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too.

Comment: Does it give some kind of error message when they try to open it on their iPad's? Is it just "unrecognizable file type" or something like that?

Comment: @CaptJak it's sort of about programming but not about iOS or Excel programming so the tags are all wrong.

Comment: You could use this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xml-viewer/id360965979?mt=8 for your clients to read your xml files. Or do you want to make your own app to do the same thing?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, I guess it could be, but he is not dealing with code at all. He wants to find out why the xml/xls files aren't working on iOS devices... Or is there another point I am missing?

Comment: @CaptJak you are probably right.

Comment: @CaptJak - You **ARE** right.  This was more suited to Superuser.  At your suggestion I posted [there](http://superuser.com/questions/634262/creating-readable-xml-for-ios), and got a helpful response.  Thank you to everyone who posted a reply here.  I'll know better next time.